# Class Cast Exception in htmldriver

Tags: java, selenium, htmlunit-driver

When I am loading a webpage in selenium html driver, there is Javascript execution error, but there is also this in the error logs

> java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.Window cannot be cast to
>   com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.Console     at
>   com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.Console.error(Console.java:132)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

I have checked error method in the Console class

```
/**
 * This method performs logging to the console at "error" level.
 * @param cx the JavaScript context
 * @param thisObj the scriptable
 * @param args the arguments passed into the method
 * @param funObj the function
 */
@JsxFunction
public static void error(final Context cx, final Scriptable thisObj,
    final Object[] args, final Function funObj) {
    final WebConsole webConsole = ((Console) thisObj).getWebConsole();
    final Formatter oldFormatter = webConsole.getFormatter();
    webConsole.setFormatter(FORMATTER_);
    webConsole.error(args);
    webConsole.setFormatter(oldFormatter);
}
```

All Scriptable objects are not subclasses of console, so why is this here?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reporting.

This has been fixed in [2.25-SNAPSHOT](https://ci.canoo.com/teamcity/viewLog.html?buildTypeId=HtmlUnit_FastBuild&buildId=lastSuccessful&tab=artifacts) by [this commit](https://sourceforge.net/p/htmlunit/code/13608/).